# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Number Of Returned Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to fetch data from a stored procedure in to jQuery datatables. For some reason it's throwing this error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mesa = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    filename: "ReturnReportsCount",
    responsive: true,
    "bAutoWidth": false, // toggle this depending on how wide you want the table
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/Controller/storedprocedure",
      "type": "GET",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "deferRender": true,
    "responsive": true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    "bSort": false,
    buttons: [
      'excel', 'print'
    ],
    "columns": [
      "Number Of Returned Files",
      "Percentage Of Returned Files"
    ]
```

Comment: It sounds like the JSON that's being returned from the controller isn't in the proper format. See https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax for the expected structure of the AJAX.

Comment: Pretty straight forward: You are simply using [columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) the wrong way ....(click on link to documentation)

Comment: @davidkonrad you are referring to using columns like this?   "columns": [
                "Number Of Returned Files",
                "Percentage Of Returned Files"
            ],

Comment: @Minhal, I believe the values in the array is meant as titles? Then it should be `columns: [ { title: "Number Of Returned Files" }, {  title: "Percentage Of Returned Files" }]` You need to provide either an object literal or a `null` value....

Comment: @davidkonrad yes they are column names from a stored procedure. "columns": [
                { title: "Number Of Returned Files" },
                { title: "Percentage Of Returned Files" }
            ]

Comment: @davidkonrad I have tried this way as well its not working